# Multiple database connectivity

Tags: database, oracle, sql-server-2005, db2, database-connection

We have 4 products and each supports below 4 datasources.

1. Oracle
2. SQL server 2005
3. DB2
4. Datopia

Now We are building Administration product which will interact will all the products and hence their databases.We have some requirements where we have to access tables from different datasources in a single query.We initially thought of using Oracle transparent gateway to create DB links and then access tables in different datasources. But this requires oracle to be installed for one of the products. This restrictions cannot be brought in our environment(For example among 4 products 2 may have SQL server installation and other two may have DB2 installation). Which is the best way to connect to all datasources with out any restriction. One more thing, we are using java to connect to these databases. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what kind of framework your client software uses.  But if it uses Java, dotnet, or PERL, you will be able to use that framework's data access modules to connect to the various table servers.  You can connect to all of them from a single client process easily enough.

You db access won't be perfectly transparent. You'll need some aspects of your program to be Oracle- or SQL-Server- specific, for example.  On the other hand, if you do this right, it won't be hard to add MySQL and PostgreSQL support if your customers need it.

You'll have a fairly steep QA burden -- you'll need to test with at least one and two instances of all four table servers connected simultaneously to make sure everything works.

But this kind of product usually has high value, so you should be able to justify the QA effort.

Comment: Thnk for reply, We have some requirements where we have to access tables from different datasources in a single query. using data modules u have specified does not solve our problem.